# ng-Table can not get data to load

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I cant seem to get my ng-table running. 
I get error saying  newParams.reload is not a function.
tried finding something online for it and tweak my code a little but still cant seem to get it working.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.bridge")
        .controller("bridgeController", bridgeController);

    function bridgeController($scope, authService, bridgeService, briges, NgTableParams) {

        $scope.isBridgeSelected = false;

        $scope.bridgeModel = {}
        $scope.selectedBridge = {}
        $scope.bridgeDetails = {};

        $scope.bridgeKeyValue = briges.data;


        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({

        },
        {
            total: $scope.bridgeKeyValue.length,
            getData: function () {
                console.log("inside getData");
                $scope.data = briges.data;
            }
        });



    }
})();
```

And my HTML is this

```
 <table ng-table="bridgeKeyValue" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                            <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
                                <td data-title="' # '">{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                <td data-title="'Bridge Name'" filter="{BridgeName: 'text'}">{{row.Name}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

I dont see my log as well.

Could you please guide me to proper direction please? im not sure what im doing wrong at this point.
Thank you!

Comment: `ng-table="bridgeKeyValue"` should be `ng-table="tableParams"`

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you! you totally right!